# How to get links from text file using python

Tags: python, text

So i have a text file that looks like this

```
randomthings inside text file "https://linkforvideo.mp4" a lot more random things "https://linkforphoto.jpg"
```

i want to print the links that ends with ".mp4" in a clickable format.
How can i do this using python?

Comment: Where do you want to "print" the links? In the console? in an IDE? Jupyter will automatically make links clickable when printed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using the [Regular expresion library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
   import re 
    word = 'randomthings inside text file "https://linkforvideo.mp4" a lot more random things "https://linkforphoto.jpg"'
    link=[]
    result = re.search('https://(.*?).mp4', word)
    while True:
        try:
            result_string = result.group(0)
            link.append(result_string)
            word= word.replace(result_string, "")
            result = re.search('https://(.*?).mp4', word)
        except : break
    print(link)
```

Here you are filtering the result to only get the strings that starts with "https://" and ends with ".mp4", after you get the string, you delete the founded string from "word" and run the program again until there is no match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry i didn't see that earlier. My friend suggested a similar way to yours and both of your answers are working. Thank you again